# Adding Maki Icon to Legend in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I cannot find a way to show in the Legend the Bus icon from Maki.

What should I write in the custom HTML?

http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/bus-18.svg)"> Greyhound Station

Answer (score 3):

This code adds a legend with the bus icon from Maki:

```
<div class='cartodb-legend custom'>
<ul>
<li class="bkg">
    <div class="bullet" style="background:url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/bus-18.svg)"></div>
    Test-legend
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Image:

[image]